# The previous screen that transited by pushViewController is blank

Tags: swift

It is transitioning with navigationPush. However, we are in trouble because nothing is displayed on the transition destination.

Confirmation of careless mistake, confirmation of lifecycle designation, etc., I will not cure it at all

”Transition destination”

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MeasureViewController: UIViewController {

    private enum MeasureIndexPathItem: Int {
        case measureCannotCell = 0
        case measureNotCell = 1
        case measureTextCell = 2
    }

    private lazy var measureTableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(MeasureCannotTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MeasureCannotTableViewCell.self))
        tableView.register(MeasureNotTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MeasureNotTableViewCell.self))
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupUI()
    }
    }

    extension MeasureViewController {
            private func setupUI() {
                view.addSubview(measureTableView)
                measureTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 44).isActive = true
                measureTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                measureTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.size.width).isActive = true
            }
    }

    extension MeasureViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 3
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let indexPathItem = MeasureIndexPathItem(rawValue: indexPath.item) else { return UITableViewCell() }
            switch indexPathItem {
            case .measureCannotCell:
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MeasureCannotTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? MeasureCannotTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
                cell.configureInit(labelText: "測定不能")
                return cell
            case .measureNotCell:
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MeasureNotTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? MeasureNotTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.configureInit(labelText: "測定不能")
            return cell
        case .measureTextCell:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MeasureTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as? MeasureTextCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

”Transition source”

```
let viewController = MeasureViewController()
viewController.navigationItem.title = menuTitle[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

I want to display the component firmly on the View.

Comment: you didn't set constraints for your tableView correctly. you need to add leading and trailing constraints too.

Comment: Also, check navigationController isn't nil when you 're trying to push your viewController.